# Drupal 8 WYSIWYG data programatically insertion make display plain html

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am working with some migration of content from one website to another. I am doing this using a cron.

When I try to insert data to the WYSIWYG fields the data is inserted and showing in the WYSIWYG editor, but when I check this data in the front-end, the data seems to be pure HTML. Does anybody know what type of formatting I have to apply for proper insertion of data?

Comment: Hey hey, could you please add some sample code or detailed description of how you actually migrate the data?

Comment: Your problem is probably not the input format, but it is the text format selected for the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for this,

I added the below code

```
$node->set('field_textarea_data', ['format'=>'full_html','value'=>html_entity_decode($data->data,ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')]);
```

And this solved my issue.

Thanks all for your response.